# Custom analyzer doesn't work when searching Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

I create `documents` index with type `_doc`. Then I
**Setup a custom analyzer** as follow

```
POST /documents/_close
PUT /documents/_settings
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "custom_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "word_delimiter_graph"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "question": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
            },
            "question_group": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
POST /documents/_open
```

I try to use this `custom_analyzer` then it works

```
POST http://localhost:9200/documents/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
  "text": "FIRE_DETECTED"
}
# And the result (lowercase and remove _ )
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "fire",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "detected",
            "start_offset": 5,
            "end_offset": 13,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I try searching "fire" or "fire detected", **it doesn't work**.

When I try searching "fire_detected", **it still works**
(I indexed "FIRE_DETECTED")

```
#This POST found nothing
POST /documents/_search
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "fire detected",
            "fields": [
                "question^2",
                "question_group"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Solution**

**Try to create a new index with new setting (above)**

```
PUT /documents5
{
    "settings": {...}
}
```

**Index data**

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/documents5/_doc/1
{
  "question": "fire_detected"
}
```

**Search**

Answer (score 1):

This happened as you just added the definition of your `custom_analyzer` to your index, but didn't reindex the data(documents in your index), hence new tokens are not present in the inverted index. **In order to fix the issue, just reindex again the documents which you want to come in your search result.**

You are using the `multi_match` query which internally uses the `match` query and these queries are analyzed so you don't need the search time analyzer.

`match` queries uses the same analyzer which is defined on the field to create the search tokens(ie which is created from the search terms).

From the [match query official docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html)

> Returns documents that match a provided text, number, date or boolean
> value. **The provided text is analyzed before matching.**

Comment: 1. I created a new index `new_documents`    2. Then I setup a customer analyzer to `new_documents` index   3. I reindex `documents` index to `new_documents`     4. I try POST `/_analyze`, it works    5. But when i tried to search, it still found nothing...

Comment: @TranDinhHuy strange I just tried your sample data and it works for me, can you show your index request, make sure, that you indexed the data in your `question` and `question_group` field

Comment: Please see my edited post. Begin from "Try to create a new index"

Comment: @TranDinhHuy interesting, but one thing I didn't understand why you are closing and opening a index, on new index, you can simply have this analyzer specified and index docs, I am hoping you are indexing doc after having this analyzer setting

Comment: If i don't close index, then I POST `/documents/_settings` , it show error `"type": "illegal_argument_exception"` and `"reason": "Can't update non dynamic settings [[index.analysis.analyzer.custom_analyzer.tokenizer, index.analysis.analyzer.custom_analyzer.type, index.analysis.analyzer.custom_analyzer.filter]] for open indices [[documents/wUbjvnbWSiCeRfEsKIT8ag]]"`.

Comment: By the way, If i create a new index with new setting at the same time. IT WORKS.

Comment: @TranDinhHuy :) thats what I was mentioning, but even if you add a analyzer later on it should work , you need to follow below steps 
1) create index without custom analyzer 2) close index, 3) add custom analyzer 4) open index 5) index a document 6) search the doc, lmk if you are following the all the steps in order

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222284/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-tran-dinh-huy).